block diagram of diagnosing genetic disorders using deep learning models
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title{Block Diagram of AI Diagnosis of Genetic Disorders}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section*{Block Diagram}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, font=\small]
    % Define blocks
    \node (data) [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20] {Data Collection and Preprocessing};
    \node (preproc) [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!10, below of=data] {Normalization \\ Data Augmentation};
    \node (design) [rectangle, draw, fill=green!20, below of=preproc] {Model Architecture Design};
    \node (cnn) [rectangle, draw, fill=green!10, below of=design, xshift=-2cm] {CNN for Image Data};
    \node (rnn) [rectangle, draw, fill=green!10, below of=design, xshift=2cm] {RNN/LSTM for Sequence};
    \node (train) [rectangle, draw, fill=red!20, below of=cnn, yshift=-1cm] {Training Process};
    \node (init) [rectangle, draw, fill=red!10, below of=train, xshift=-2cm] {Initialization};
    \node (forward) [rectangle, draw, fill=red!10, below of=train] {Forward Propagation};
    \node (loss) [rectangle, draw, fill=red!10, below of=train, xshift=2cm] {Loss Calculation};
    \node (backward) [rectangle, draw, fill=red!10, below of=train, xshift=4cm] {Backward Propagation};
    \node (iter) [rectangle, draw, fill=red!10, below of=backward] {Iteration};
    \node (reg) [rectangle, draw, fill=purple!20, below of=iter, yshift=-1cm] {Regularization and Hyperparameter Tuning};
    \node (regular) [rectangle, draw, fill=purple!10, below of=reg, xshift=-2cm] {Apply Dropout, L2 Regularization, \\ Batch Normalization};
    \node (optimize) [rectangle, draw, fill=purple!10, below of=reg, xshift=2cm] {Optimize Hyperparameters};
    \node (output) [rectangle, draw, fill=orange!20, below of=optimize, yshift=-1cm] {Prediction and Output};
    \node (predict) [rectangle, draw, fill=orange!10, below of=output, xshift=-2cm] {Provide Predictions};
    \node (visualize) [rectangle, draw, fill=orange!10, below of=output, xshift=2cm] {Visualization and Interpretation};

    % Draw connections
    \draw[->] (data) -- (preproc);
    \draw[->] (preproc) -- (design);
    \draw[->] (design) -- (cnn);
    \draw[->] (design) -- (rnn);
    \draw[->] (cnn) -- (train);
    \draw[->] (rnn) -- (train);
    \draw[->] (train) -- (init);
    \draw[->] (train) -- (forward);
    \draw[->] (train) -- (loss);
    \draw[->] (train) -- (backward);
    \draw[->] (train) -- (iter);
    \draw[->] (iter) -- (reg);
    \draw[->] (reg) -- (regular);
    \draw[->] (reg) -- (optimize);
    \draw[->] (optimize) -- (output);
    \draw[->] (output) -- (predict);
    \draw[->] (output) -- (visualize);
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{Detailed Block Diagram}

\begin{align*}
\text{Data Collection and Preprocessing} & \rightarrow \text{Normalization} \rightarrow \text{Data Augmentation} \\
\text{Model Architecture Design} & \rightarrow \text{CNN for Image Data} \\
& \rightarrow \text{RNN/LSTM for Sequence} \\
\text{Training Process} & \rightarrow \text{Initialization} \rightarrow \text{Forward Propagation} \rightarrow \text{Loss Calculation} \rightarrow \text{Backward Propagation} \rightarrow \text{Iteration} \\
\text{Regularization and Hyperparameter Tuning} & \rightarrow \text{Apply Dropout, L2 Regularization, Batch Normalization} \rightarrow \text{Optimize Hyperparameters} \\
\text{Prediction and Output} & \rightarrow \text{Provide Predictions} \rightarrow \text{Visualization and Interpretation}
\end{align*}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do not only show a code, explain also what is your issue in your words and show us the first error message you got!

Answer deal only with diagram, so other content of MWE (Minimal Working Example) in your question I left to you.
It is not entirely clear how your image should looks. I guess, that something close to the following:

Is this what you after?
I try to make your code shorter. For this I define common style for nodes. Since image is quite wide, I also break text in the most cells into two or three lines:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=4mm and 3mm, 
arr/.style = {-Straight Barb},
every edge/.append style = {draw, arr},
N/.style = {draw, fill=#1, align=center, font=\footnotesize, minimum size=3em}
                        ]
    % Define blocks
\node (data)    [N=blue!20]                     {Data Collection\\ and Preprocessing};
\node (preproc) [N=blue!10, below=of data]      {Normalization \\ Data Augmentation};
\node (design)  [N=green!20,below=of preproc]   {Model Architecture\\ Design};
\node (cnn)     [N=green!10, below left=of design.south]   {CNN for\\ Image Data};
\node (rnn)     [N=green!10, below right=of design.south]   {RNN/LSTM\\ for Sequence};
%
\node (train)   [N=red!20, below=of design |- cnn.south]    {Training\\ Process};
\node (init)    [N=red!10, below=of train, xshift=-5cm]     {Initialization};
\node (forward) [N=red!10, right=of init]       {Forward\\ Propagation};
\node (loss)    [N=red!10, right=of forward]    {Loss\\ Calculation};
\node (backward) [N=red!10, right=of loss]      {Backward\\ Propagation};
\node (iter)    [N=red!10, right=of backward]   {Iteration};
%
\node (reg)     [N=purple!20, below left=of iter.south east]    {Regularization and\\ Hyperparameter Tuning};
%
\node (regular) [N=purple!10, below left=of reg.south]  {Apply Dropout,\\ 
                                                         L2 Regularization, \\ 
                                                         Batch Normalization};
\node (optimize) [N=purple!10, right=of regular]        {Optimize\\ Hyperparameters};
%
\node (output) [N=orange!20, below=of optimize]  {Prediction and Output};
%
\node (predict) [N=orange!10, below left=of output.south] {Provide\\ Predictions};
\node (visualize) [N=orange!10, below right=of output.south] {Visualization\\ and Interpretation};
% Draw connections
\draw   (data)  edge  (preproc)     (preproc)  edge  (design) 
        (design)  edge  (cnn)       (design)  edge  (rnn)       
        (cnn)  edge  (train)        (rnn)  edge  (train)        
        (train)  edge  (forward)    (train)  edge  (loss) 
        (train)  edge  (backward)   (iter)  edge  (reg) 
        (reg)  edge  (regular)      (reg)  edge  (optimize) 
        (optimize)  edge  (output)  (output)  edge  (predict) 
        (output)  edge  (visualize);
\draw[->] (train) -| (init);
\draw[->] (train) -| (iter);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

